# PDO return same result no matter using INT or not

Tags: php, mysql, post, pdo, int

The table design in my database as follow,

```
 AID  INT(10)  AUTO_INCREMENT    
 ID   INT(20)  
 DATA VARCHAR(50)
 Engine = MyISAM
```

I make a form in order to POST data to a function which executes the SQL query.

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" >
   <input type="text" name="id" /><BR/>
   <input type="text" name="val1" /><BR/>
   <input type="text" name="val2" /><BR/>
   <input type="text" name="val3" /><BR/>
   <input type="submit" name= "t" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Array and echo the result:

```
if (isset($_POST['t'])){
 foreach(array($_POST) as $data) {
 echo send($data);
 } 
};
```

And here is the function:

```
    function send($data){
        //MySQL connected
        $do = $sql->prepare("SELECT id, data FROM test WHERE id =?");
        $do->bindValue(1, $data['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $do -> execute() ;
             if ( $do -> rowCount()=== 1){
                 $getData = $do -> fetch();
                  return $getData['data'];
            }
}
```

When POST form using '1' in 'id' field , the function return the 'data' fetched from the table.

However, when using '1aaxxacac' to POST the form, the function returned the same result.

I've already tried to use:

```
          $do -> execute(array(':id'=>$data['id]));
```

to replace the previous one but still has the same problem.
If I changed the ID field from INT to CHAR or VARCHAR in MySQL, the situation was solved.

Sincerely hope you guys can give me a hand to figure it out.

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: @Musa Yeah so should I use is_numeric ? But how to integrate it with my foreach? And I found some websites consider is_numeric has bad performance. However, thank you

Comment: delete these sites from your bookmarks or - better - ban them on your firewall

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues involved

1. One is mysql-related, a widely known one, called "loose typing". Mysql will try to cast your data before using it:

   ```
   mysql> select id from board where id='2foo';
   +----+
   | id |
   +----+
   |  2 |
   +----+
   ```
2. Another is PDO-related and quite a strange one: `PDO::PARAM_INT` **doesn't cast string value to int**. It tests value type and binds accordingly: so, it only binds value as int if it's already of int (or bool) type. Otherwise it's bound as string and sent to mysql as is.  I've no idea why does it behave such a strange way, so, it have to be just remembered.

I see not much a problem here though.

Comment: Thank you,and could you please give me some tips to fix it? I think use there would be other methods except is_numeric. Much thanks

Comment: I honestly can't see what to fix here. Can you explain what certain problem you face? Your app is malfunction due to this? It produces some error? Or what?

Comment: When user type a string which contains the integer still can get the function processed. How to prevent this except using jquery to validate the form.

Comment: I cannot get neither your problem with string value nor with is_numeric() function. It seems you just like to bug yourself with non-existent problems.